# Mod function in GRASS GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator

What is the equal of ArcGIS Raster calculator "Mod" function (Finds the remainder of the first raster when divided by the second raster on a cell-by-cell basis.) in r. mapcalc in GRASS GIS?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function, but you can use the modulus operator, which is "%" in GRASS (as in many other languages), e.g. 8%5=3

for a pixel-by-pixel computation, simply use the layer names

```
layerOne%layerTwo
```

Comment: This is what I would do in ArcGIS raster calculator:           "tmp7 = Mod(((450 - (ATan2(tmp5, tmp6) * 57.296)) * 100), 36000) / 100". What would its equal be in GRASS GIS?                                                   I have tried             "tmp7 = (((450 - (atan(tmp5@maria, tmp6@maria ) * 57.296)) * 100), 36000) %100 " but it gives a parse error.

Comment: @marika That sounds like a new question so I think you should consider accepting this answer and asking a new question that includes the precise error message.

Comment: @PolyGeo, thank you! Here I have began a new question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151693/linearising-aspect-in-grass-gis